# Непрерывное соединение с сервером

Tags: java, android, сервер, сокет

Есть сервер, к которому мое приложение подключается посредством `Socket`. Нужно держать постоянный коннект, чтобы обходить ситуации, когда пропадает интернет. Нужно решение, по типу всех популярных мессенджеров, после того, как соединение с Интернет возобновиться, заново коннектиться к серверу.

Пробовал работать с `ConnectivityManager`, но в ситуациях не моментального отключения от сети, а допустим, постепенного отдаления от точки WiFi, он срабатывает неправильно. Да и в Android 7.0 эти события не приходят в автоматическим режиме.

Нужен постоянный коннект, который будет разрываться когда интернета нет, и восстанавливаться, когда он снова появится.

Есть идеи, как поступить?

Comment: Это плохая практика, приложение будет сильно потреблять батарею.

Comment: Используйте Firebase Cloud Messages для передачи данных клиентам, когда приложение в бэкграунде. Это решение соответствует популярным мессенджерам, а не поддержка соединения.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov это ведь облачное решение, а мне нужно нативное

Comment: А что Вы понимаете под терминами "облачное" и "нативное", применимо к этой ситуации? Я могу с уверенностью сказать, что приложения не держат постоянный коннект с сервером. А уведомить устройство можно двумя основными способами: GCM и FCM. Лучше FCM, первый уже устаревает, да и не оч удобно возиться с ним.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov поясню. У меня есть сервер, к которому я подключаюсь по TCP, и FCM подразумевает наличие у меня Cloud Messaging Server, чего мне не нужно. Общение должно происходить с моим, существующим сервером

Comment: Вам не нужно подключать весь стек технологий Firebase. Механизм прост: регистрируете Ваше приложение в Firebase консоли, добавляете Firebase в приложении, при запуске приложения получаете Firebase токен и отдаете его Вашему серверу. Ваш сервер, как будет необходимо уведомить клиента, выполняет обычный post запрос в FCM с данными и токеном конкретного устройства (который устройство отослало ранее). И Firebase сразу же пришлет данные в сервис в приложении. Тут FCM является просто мостом. Вся логика по-прежнему на Вашем сервере.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov но если мне нужно, чтобы приложение работало и в локальной сети, без доступа к Интернету?

Comment: Это ж как? Если сервер удаленный, то используется его внешний ip. Если Вы подключитесь в локальную сеть к серверу, то нужно будет использовать уже внутренний ip. Или у Вас в коде попытки создать коннект на оба ip адреса?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57327/discussion-between-heorhii-lysenko-and-vladimir-parfenov).